# Unable to create a .txt file in Android using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to make an Android app using Kotlin.
I’m having some problems for creating a .txt file on my virtual device using Android Studio. Code is as below:

```
val ruta: String = "documento.txt"
val f = File(ruta)
if (f.exists() == false) {
    f.createNewFile()
    Toast.makeText(this, "Document created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

I’ve noticed that the app is running on / (root) so I decided to give permissions in the manifest.
I wrote this inside manifest but nothing happened:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Result in the logcat is this: `java.io.IOException: Permission denied.`

I have tried moving the directory for creating the file but I continue to not obtain the file.

Comment: Did you try to add runtime permission? 
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
// IF not granted
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUEST)
}

Comment: You should use a full path. Not only a file name.

Comment: In my case, this code is not working. Be that as it may, thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the permission denied exception because you are trying to create a file in the root directory of the file system. Only the `root` user can access the root directory (but all installed apps a assigned a user ID != root).

What you can do instead is to create a file in your application-private files directory:

```
val file = File(context.filesDir, "doc.txt")
file.createNewFile()
```

Comment: `You are getting the permission denied exception because you are trying to create a file in the root directory of the file system` No. Because only a file name is used instead of a full parh.

Comment: @blackapps FYI the constructor of `File` accepts `pathname`. `File("doc.txt").absoluteFile == "/doc.txt"`. This is a file in the root directory, reserved for the root user.

Comment: Yes. So not usable for normal actions.  A full path has to be used.

Comment: Yes, given that the app possesses the file-system permission required by the file / directory.

Comment: For .filesDir no permission is needed. And on Android 14+ devices one cannot even request WRITE permission for external storage.

Comment: I'm talking about UNIX permissions, not Manifest permissions. The permissions for the `filesDir` for example are `drwxrwx--x`. It means that only the owner (your app) can read and write files in it.